# zend decorator, adding an empty element before submit button

Tags: zend-framework, decorator, zend-decorators

```
$submit->setDecorators(array('ViewHelper',

           array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'td', 'class'=>'element')),
           array(array('emptyrow'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'td', 'class'=>'element')),
           array(array('row'=> 'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'tr'))
        ));
```

I want to get the following out put.

```
<tr><td class="element">&nbps;</td><td class="element">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></td></tr>
```

But as we know above code will wrap td around another td. like this

```
<tr><td class="element"><td class="element">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"></td></td></tr>
```

I know that I can remove the emptyrow line entirly and use colspans as properties. but i don't want to go that why. I want to know how we can create a elment sibilling with other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `placement` option to `emptyrow`

```
$submit->setDecorators(array(
   'ViewHelper',
   array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'td', 'class'=>'element')),
   array(array('emptyrow'=>'HtmlTag'), array('placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::PREPEND, 'tag'=>'td', 'class'=>'element')),
   array(array('row'=> 'HtmlTag'), array('tag'=>'tr'))
));
```

Comment: Oh. Yes. I totally forget about that Placement thing. Yes. it works. we can also use the simple 'prepend' without abstract. 
array(array('emptyrow'=>'HtmlTag'), array('placement' => 'prepend', 'tag'=>'td', 'class'=>'element')),